# Write JSON Data From "Requests" Python Module to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, python-requests

[JSON data output when printed in command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz8SX.png) I am currently pulling data via an API and am attempting to write the data into a CSV in order to run calculations in SQL. I am currently able to pull the data, open the CSV, however an error occurs when the data is being written into the CSV. The error is that each individual character is separated by a comma.

I am new to working with JSON data so I am curious if I need to perform an intermediary step between pulling the JSON data and inserting it into a CSV. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stuck on this (even the data provider does not seem to know how to get around this).

Please see the code below:

```
import requests
import time
import pyodbc
import csv
import json

headers = {'Authorization': 'Token'}

Metric1 = ['Website1','Website2']
Metric2 = ['users','hours','responses','visits']
Metric3 = ['Country1','Country2','Country3']

obs_list = []
obs_file = r'TEST.csv'
with open(obs_file, 'w') as csvfile:
   f=csv.writer(csvfile)
   for elem1 in Metric1:
        for elem2 in Metric2:
            for elem3 in Metric3:
                    URL = "www.data.com"
                    r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, verify=False)
                    for elem in r:
                    f.writerow(elem) `
```

Edit: When I print the data instead of writing it to a CSV, the data appears in the command window in the following format:

[timestamp, metric], [timestamp, metric], [timestamp, metric] ...

Timestamp = 12 digit character

Metric = decimal value

Comment: Show your json data. And the desired csv format.

Comment: Try to use `r.json()` to format data first

Comment: I added a link to a screenshot of the JSON data output when it is printed in the command line.

Comment: Shane - I apologize but I am still somewhat new to Python. I use r.json() when printing in the command line, however whenever I try to insert that command within the writrerow command it throws an error. Where should I include the r.json()? Thanks!